# VBA ADO connection string for a workbook with a path that contains space and comma

Tags: excel, vba, connection-string, ado, adodb

How can I make this work? If the workbook path does not have any space or comma it works just fine, but implementing OneDrive has messed up the workbook path, which is supposed to work as a database address.

I have wrapped it around quotes, but that did not work too.

I am getting this error:

External table is not in the expected format.

[image]

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

With cnn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Users\abc\OneDrive - My Company, Inc\Desktop\Form_v.0.996.xlsm;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1'"
    .Open
End With
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you tried `Data Source='C:\Users\abc\OneDrive - My Company, Inc\Desktop\Form_v.0.996.xlsm';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1'"`?

Comment: @Profex yes, I tried it

Comment: If I specify a bad path, the error says, "not a valid path", but as your error is about a External Table/Format.  I think there is something wrong with the file.

Comment: yeah, the file was opened readonly

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was: I was opening the workbook `ReadOnly:=True`, which is not accepted as a proper format for a database by ADO